# Remove header of a json file, symfony2

Tags: php, json, symfony

So, i have an array in PHP, and i write to convert this array to a json and then write this json in a file .json :

```
$fs = new Filesystem();
$fs->dumpFile('test.json', new JsonResponse($this->data));
```

I'm using filesystem from symfony 2 and JsonResponse to convert array in json.

but with this code, in my file test.json, i have this header :

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type:  application/json
Date:          Wed, 11 Dec 2013 18:30:19 GMT
```

How can i simply remove this header ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to save JSON-encoded array into a file, you don't need to use JsonResponse, simple [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) will suffice.

This may look something like this:

```
$fs = new Filesystem();
$fs->dumpFile('test.json', json_encode($this->data));
```